# How to : ElasticSearch .NET and NEST 5.X Multimatch with wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, nest

I has been search a lot of sample from Internet, however i still could not find any sample on Wildcard Search with more than one fields, can anyone help me with some example? Im very new into ElasticSearch. Below is what im trying to do with wildcard, but it work for one field.

How can i combine below Wildcard with MultiMatch in C#?

```
var result = client.Search<Metadata>(x => x                  
     .Index("indexname")
     .Type("Metadata")    
     .MatchAll()                    
     .Query(q => q
             .Wildcard(c => c
                .Name("Query")
                .Boost(1.1)                        
                .Field(p => p.Title)  
                .Value("input*")
                .Rewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBoost(10))
            )  
)                                                         
);
```

How can i add in below multi fields support like in Multimatch?
    .Fields(f => f
        .Fields(f1 => f1.Title, f2 => f2.Keywords)
     )

Comment: Have you considered using a custom analyzer that incorporates edgengram token filter? Usually, wildcard queries are not what you _really_ need for full-text search. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html

Comment: Thanks for the hits :)